# How can I get pre-release reviews of my mobile game?

Tags: android, ipad, casual-games, arcade

My iOS and Android game is at its last stage of development. Is there a way for me to get pre-release reviews from people? Or maybe from the press? How should I proceed?

Comment: please change the title, it sounds like this is self-promotion spam

Comment: @jhocking there's nothing preventing you from suggesting an edit.

Comment: oh yeah, I forgot

Answer (score 1):

Giving it away for free to a SMALL(ER) ammount of people. Using the Redeem code option over on the Appstore, you can give payed versions of the game for free. But it will work slower / have effect on a smaller group of people, I'd go with another technique which is widely used.

Distribute it and do the following:

Add a pop up - Rate us after 15+ minutes of playing.

1)

> People make the game price free for a limited time period. The Fruit Ninja did that, once they have become popular they  released the "lite version" next to the paid version which contains less features. That way, when someone sees the full version of Fruit ninja at someones phone, he might want to buy it.

2)

> Depending on the game, if you made a role playing game, with a story
>   that drives the players attention. You can create the first  chapter
>   (however it is called) playable to anyone and once the player wants to
>   hear the rest of the story and he likes the game, he will buy it.
>   "Horn" by Zynga has used this technique. (Sadly, it worked on me).
>   This will get you both, more sells and reviews

Comment: Almost none of those options apply to pre-release.

Comment: HI thanks for the replies. someone has edited the post. though the oveall theme remains same but it was not sounding like an self promotion

Comment: Didn't seem to me. You asked for the way to "SELF PROMOTE" yourself once the product is finished, get a feedback from press etc. Appstore is a huge dump with some "pearls" like angry birds etc. You can deliver your product as a Beta/Lite version to get a feedback. And then make a paid version which would act like a released version. Hard to tell from your situation. If you want to have just 15 people you can use the redeem code option in the appstore, you will have to create it for those people only. THey will play a bit, and after that you will quickly update the game version

Comment: On the Google Play/Appstore you do not sell the Boxed version and you can start distributing it with some glitches in the "beta" => change the name of it crossing out the "beta V." and people who played it will get the update automatically. If you were selling physical copies of a Nintendo 3ds game you would have a problem in creating the updates. But updating a game version on an Iphone is a matter of downloading it, and unpacking the update on your mobile phone. That is why I wouldn't stick to the "Pre release", I'd just release it, hand over the link to press etc. and later start promoting